# Not sure why mysql event is not running

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql-event

My site has a video gallery in which only videos 2 weeks old or less should be displayed. Previously I was running a simple update query that ran whenever ANY user came to this page as follows:

```
$unixtime = time();

$query = mysqli_query($cxn, "UPDATE vids SET status = 'inactive' WHERE status = 'active' AND 1209600 < ($unixtime - uploadtime)");
```

I recently became aware of events and stored procedures, and figured this would save many queries by simply running this query as an event once every 24 hours at a specific time (and removing the query above from the page where this query is currently found). I'm using phpMyAdmin v.4.1.8 (shared hosting) and MySQL 5.1.73 (event support seems to have existed since MySQL 5.1.6) and cannot get it to work! Here's my query (since the query does not return anything, I considered this an "event", though I know a "procedure" also doesn't need to return anything):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mysite`@`localhost` 
EVENT `videodeactivate` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS '2015-02-21 10:45:00' 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO 
UPDATE myschema.vids SET status = 'inactive' 
WHERE status = 'active' 
AND 1209600 < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - uploadtime);
```

(Note: 1209600 seconds = 2 weeks)

The update is not occurring, although the event has definitely been scheduled (I see it as a little red-outline clock right above "Tables" for this database, and when I click the clock the procedure is labeled as ENABLED). I have edited the event to remove "myschema" (so UPDATE vids SET....) and have even removed the AND clause. No errors are being thrown, but the event doesn't seem to run.

Why is this event, which definitely appears to be "scheduled" in phpMyAdmin as far as I can tell, not running? If all else fails I can manually run a query to deactivate these 2+ week old videos, but I would like to see this event work.

Comment: if you echo the upload time, is that the same format as $unixtime? let me know how you get the uploadtime into variable

Comment: Yes, all the times here (time(), uploadtime, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ) are INT

Comment: uploadtime is just a column with an INT value that represents a UNIX timestamp of each video's time of upload

Comment: I just tried with me and it works. I didn't find the problem.

Comment: @don, perhaps it must be change into date and time, not Integer

Comment: @don, using phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Sure, I do. I'm confused now ... Lolz, by the way, how do you setup your connection then?

Comment: I'm running the Event query from the phpMyAdmin...connection is established by default because I run other queries from phpMyAdmin command line without any connection query...my first query at the top was from a php script which used a mysqli_connect but the event is from phpMyAdmin

Comment: do you get error msg? I wonder if this is version issue of your phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Jean Gkol and Don, thank you for your responses. I called my hosting service and they said there is no error in the MySQL error log and that the Event should work. They couldn't find anything wrong with it....only possibility I could think of is that there's some server setting they have enabled that blocks the execution of MySQL Procedures and Events (as some kind of precautionary measure). I doubled checked and the query DOES successfully run from command line, so my guess is the issue must be on the hosting service's end.

Comment: nice. and now answer your question by yourself to let other knows that this is successfully solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got an email from my web hosting service (JustHost). Apparently, root access is necessary to be able to schedule an Event and have it executed...One more reason to host your own website :)